# How to implement a loop for incrementing data

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make my program smarter by using loops in c++. I hit a mental block when trying to solve this problem because I'm trying to keep track of so many counters. More important than the correct code, how do I approach thinking about the problem correctly as to come to the right conclusion?

I've tried a for loop and think a nested for loop might be necessary but I can't figure out how to continually add the monthDays[] values to properly examine the input and make the right decision.

The input is a user defined number less than 366 but more than 0.
The program is meant to return the month name and the days passed in that month.

```
string monthNames[12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April"};
int monthDays[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30};   


if ((input - monthDays[0]) <=  0){

    cout << monthNames[0] << " " << input;
    }

      else if (input < (monthDays[0] + monthDays[1]) &&  
              (input > monthDays[0]){

        cout << monthNames[1] << " " << (input - monthDays[0]);
     }

        else if (input < (monthDays[0] + monthDays[1] + monthDays[2]) &&
                input > (monthDays[0] + monthDays[1])){

          cout << monthNames[2] << " " << (input - monthDays[0] - monthDays[2]);
        }

          else if (input < (monthDays[0] + monthDays[1] + monthDays[2] + monthDays[3]) &&      
                  input > (monthDays[0] + monthDays[1] + monthDays[2])){

       cout << monthNames[2] << " " << (input - monthDays[0] - monthDays[2] - monthDays[3]);
           }
```

The program works but can be simplified. How should I alter my thought process to implement looping?

Comment: What is not clear is what is your program trying to do? What is variable 'input'?

Comment: The input is a user defined number less than 366 but more than 0. The program is meant to return the month name and the days passed in that month

Comment: The indentation here is completely out of control. Can you clean that up? Understanding this code is not easy in its current form. One pattern I'm observing here is you're doing things with aggressive copy-pasting instead of employing loops. In C++ you'll want to use `for` in this case, incrementing some `month` variable until you've hit the right number of days. There's really only two counters here: The `month` and the cumulative `days` counter.

Comment: Tip: Instead of tackling this the hard way, pre-compute which day each month starts on. Change your lookup table to be `{1, 32, 60, ... }` where that indicates the start date. You could also programmatically compute this from a similar array of month lengths.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it better belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example of loop:

```cpp
    std::string monthNames[12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April"};
    int monthDays[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30};

    int dayInYear = 50; // this is your 'input' variable
    int daysPassed = 0;    
    for( int i=0; i<12; i++ ) {
        int daysOnStartOfMonth = daysPassed;
        daysPassed += monthDays[i];
        if( dayInYear <= daysPassed ) {
            std::cout << monthNames[i] << " " << (dayInYear - daysOnStartOfMonth);
            break;  // We found the month, so we can stop the loop
        }
    }
```

You can try it at http://cpp.sh/8mahf

I used variable 'dayInYear' as a counter to which I add number of days in a particular month. Then it's just about comparing this variable to your input variable (which I called 'dayInYear' as it is more descriptive name for a variable).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to print "month day", so you can simplify your logic to:

```
string monthNames[12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", /*and so on*/}; 
int monthDays[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, /*same here*/}; 
int i = 0;
/*While your input is bigger than the days of the month*/    
while(input > monthDays[i] && i < 12)
{
    input -= monthDays[i]; // subtract it
    i++;                   // and go to next month
}
//Then print the month and the day
cout << monthNames[i] << " " << input;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tidy this up a *lot* by letting the code do all the work for you. A simple `while` loop sets this out:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

const std::string monthNames[12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April"};
const int monthDays[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30};

const std::string& monthName(int index) {
  // Start testing at month index 0
  int month = 0;

  while (index > monthDays[month] && month < 12) {
    // Subtract the number of days in this month if moving on...
    index -= monthDays[month];

    // ...to the next month.
    ++month;
  }

  // Return the month found.
  return monthNames[month];
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << monthName(atoi(argv[1])) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Note that this requires a full month table to work, and will need two tables to accommodate leap-years.